# Command Prompt Error 'C:\' is not recognized as an internal or external command.., when I used C:\>netstat -ano | findstr 0.0:443 this command

Tags: apache, command-line

I am trying to find the program which used 443 this apache port.

> Apache port:443 is being used by another application.

But after I type

> C:> netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:443

this command at Command Prompt, I got

> 'C:' is not recognized as an internal or external command, operable program or batch file.

Comment: Whats the `C:>` supposed to do?

Comment: If you've copied it from somewhere: `C:\>` is meant to symbolize the command prompt - and you'd start typing the commands that follow it. It shows the current drive & directory ( `C:\ ` ) followed by a sign that now your command will follow ( `>` ). E.g. you only have to type `netstat -aon | findstr 0.0:443`